# How to ensure that an object does not have the same id?

Tags: plone, zope

Here is my problem:

I have a custom Dexterity content type that its ids **must be always** a computed value out of two fields (week and year).

What I need to ensure is that if someone tries to create a new object of that content type and uses an already existing (week, year) tuple Plone needs to give an error and ask the user to change either the week or year fields.

So I not only need to check that no other object already exists with that week and year values, but also that the object id is consistent (`WWYY`, WW for week and YY year is the format).

I first thought of an `invariant` on the content type interface, but that still leaves the id up to `INameChooser`.

So registering an `INameChooser` for the parent folder (fortunately I have a specific parent folder for that content type) can be enough?

Comment: Are your contents all in the same folder?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to say that. Yes, all my objects will be placed on the same folder, that's why a more specific ``INameChooser`` helps me there.